# Задать задержку с увеличением при след запросе? Beanshell jmeter

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

Нужно написать beanshell timer, или возможно как-нибудь иначе который будет увеличить задержку в следующем запросе на +1с. При этом уже есть собственная логика которая повторяет 1 и тот же запрос пока не придет нужный ответ (сделал через response assertion + while + if controoler). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

настройка while: ${__javaScript("${txtFound}" == "FALSE" && parseInt(${counter})<=5,)}
if: ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
sampler bean shell END: vars.put("txtFound","TRUE")

Прошу прощения если сложно для понимания

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование Beanshell - моветон, [начиная с JMeter 3.1 рекомендуется использовать Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Код для [JSR223 Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer) будет примерно таким:

```
def delay = vars.getObject('delay') ?: 0L
delay += 1000
vars.putObject('delay', delay)
return delay
```

Демо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более подробно об использовании Groovy в JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)